# How to redirect to cart

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to redirect customer on post action to cart by doing this :
`Tools::redirect('cart.php');`

Everything is working fine as long as user is not logged in, as soon as the user is logged in it only reloads the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this to achieve your point `Tools::redirect('cart?action=show');` instead of `Tools::redirect('cart.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Prestashpo 1.7 (1.7.6.2) redirect to cart

go in modules to **ps_shoppingcart**

open by text

> ps_shoppingcart.js

and find  `if (resp.modal)`

and change (inside)

```
   if (resp.modal) {         
   window.location.replace(prestashop.urls.pages.order); 
}
```